# Get resource files over internet in android

Tags: android

I have an app that displays syllabus for a university. The syllabus differs with different batches.

I have syllabus for all the batches stored as string resource file, and I want users to download syllabus for their batch only.

So what I want to do is, to take the user input on what their batch is and depending on their input I want to download the string resource file for that batch and store it on their devices for further use.

Is it possible to download and use resource files dynamically??

If so, how to do it and can I store these files on google drive and use the Drive API for retrieving these files.

I know the basics of android programming but have very little idea about using content from the net. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use Android libraries like Picasso and Retrofit. Doing something like that is not for beginners. I'd suggest you pick a less ambitious project as your first project instead.

Comment: Actually i already have a app with hard coded data . I just wanted to improve this app by making the app more dynamic

Comment: Take a look at these libraries then: https://github.com/square/retrofit (the first one is for dynamic text) http://square.github.io/picasso/ (the second one is for dynamic pictures)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download files from the Internet and store them locally, but not as resources. You can just store them in a local directory managed by your app. If you look at the directories on your device, you'll find many apps that store files. For example, look at 
    /sdcard/WhatsApp/Profile Pictures

You can read about saving files locally here:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

and here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html